# how to position buttons on left and right side of a scrollable div

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, carousel, angular-material

i'm trying to make a horizontal carousel in angular material with flex

now i have a div with scrollable content in it, i just want to place the buttons on the left and right side of the div

you can move the buttons even to the outside

i'm trying to achieve something like this:[image]

i'm attaching a codepen

https://codepen.io/williamscott701/pen/dWEjQy?editors=1010

```
 <div layout="row">
  <div flex></div>
  <div flex=80 flex-sm=100 flex-xs=100>

    <div layout="row" style="overflow: auto;" id="myDIV">

      <md-button id="left" class="md-button"> << </md-button>

      <md-button id="right" class="md-button"> >> </md-button>

      <div ng-repeat="y in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,2342,234,345,34,545,6111,567,78,69,67]">
        <md-card>
          <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
              <span class="md-headline">Card with image</span>
              <span class="md-subhead">Large</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
            <md-card-title-media>
              <div class="md-media-lg card-media"></div>
            </md-card-title-media>
          </md-card-title>
          <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
            <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
            <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
          </md-card-actions>
        </md-card>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div flex></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some simple CSS. Of course you can do that with CSS flexbox if you want.

```
#myDIV {
  position: relative;
}
#left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Just found another way to do it. But this works great! Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Good to hear that. In fact there are too many possible ways in achieving this. `float: left/right` will also work.